# Linux What are the minimum permissions required to create a link to a file?

Tags: linux, permissions

For the source directory, source file and target directory what are the minimum permissions required for each in order to create a link to a file?

Comment: A hard link or a symbolic link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need execute permission to the source directory, and write+execute permission to the target directory. Permissions on the source file are irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

For a symbolic link, You need write+execute on source directory; no permissions required on target directory or file or for it to even exist. Ofcourse, it will be useless :)

```
-bash-4.2$ ln -s /non-exist/non-existent source/target
-bash-4.2$ ls -l source/target
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 s s 23 Nov 18 00:08 source/target -> /non-exist/non-existent
-bash-4.2$ ls -ld source
d-wx------. 2 s s 19 Nov 18 00:08 source
```

For a hard link, you need write+execute on source directory; target directory should be on same filesytem and you need execute on target (and its parents) directory.

```
-bash-4.2$ ls -ld sourcedir
d-wx------. 2 s s 6 Nov 18 00:20 sourcedir
-bash-4.2$ ls -ld targetdir
d--x------. 2 s s 23 Nov 18 00:18 targetdir
-bash-4.2$ ls -li targetdir/targetfile
21236391 ----------. 1 s s 0 Nov 18 00:11 targetdir/targetfile
-bash-4.2$ ln targetdir/targetfile sourcedir/link
-bash-4.2$ ls -li sourcedir/link
21236391 ----------. 2 s s 0 Nov 18 00:11 sourcedir/link
```